# Can't make node js working on port 3000

Tags: node.js, mongodb, localhost

I have already done the same process for getting node js up and running. But, after two months, doing the exact same steps, won't make it work. I need to set up node locally and I use mongodb as well. I have downloaded the latest versions of node js, mongodb and npm.

I start the application with "node app.js" and the cursor moves to the new line and it won't say that it's listening on port 3000. This is my problem. I check the localhost:3000 on my browser but it says "This webpage is not available".

When I do "netstat -a -b" it shows that node.exe has the local address 192.168.1.125:139. And just under it says "Can not obtain ownership information".

My config file is:

```
module.exports = {
development : {
    db: {
        host : 'mongodb://localhost/ekopanelen'
    },
    app: {
        name: 'ekopanelen',
        port: 3000
    }
}   };
```

My code for starting node is:

```
var express = require('express'), 
path = require('path'),
mongoose = require("mongoose"),
fs = require('fs'),
passport = require("passport"),
favicon = require('static-favicon'),
logger = require('morgan'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
exhbs = require('express3-handlebars'),
session = require('express-session'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
/* set environment to development by default. */
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
config = require('./app/config')[env];
```

More code:

```
 if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
      });
  }); }
 module.exports = app;
```

Starting the app:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('ekopanelen'),
app = require('../../app');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
config = require('../config')[env];

 app.set('port', config.app.port || 3000);

/*
 * Start Server with port from node
*/
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
 console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone can help you without showing your server initialization code and describing the situation in more detail.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that, I just edited my question.

Comment: Is this an issue with your mongodb server? or your nodejs server?

Comment: I don't believe that it's the mongodb server because when I start mongod.exe, it says that the connection is accepted. I'm doing everything locally. And like I said, I already used the same method two months ago, but now it's not working.

Comment: So, if it's the node server that isn't started, then show us the code you use for starting the node server.  What you put in your answer is a set of config options, not the actual code for starting the server.  Is the node process running persistently?  Did node report any errors when starting?  You're not helping out here much with basic debugging steps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to node so I don't really understand how it's done. My job in this project is to adjust the code with bootstrap. But, I can't do that unless I get it working. I just edited some part of the code again, is it ok now?

Comment: The code you have shown now is getting closer.  That is the loading of a number of modules and the loading of your config.  The lines of code that actually start the server are not yet shown.  There are several ways to do that.  In my express app, it's something like this:  `var app = express(); app.listen(port);`.  Do you know how to see node errors when the server starts up because if something is broken, it is may be throwing an error which would tell you where to look for the issue.

Comment: I don't know how to see node errors, unless it shows an error automatically. For example, if I don't start mongodb, it throws an err, but in this case I don't have any error shown. I added some more code, but I don't know if that's what you need to know.

Comment: You were right, it was missing the app.listen. I checked the old code, and I pasted some part. Can you please post this as an answer "  app.listen(config.app.port, function(){
  console.log('now listening on port ' + config.app.port);
 });
:

Comment: Just post it as an answer and I will accept it as solved, because it was you that made me look for the right spot, otherwise everything was like in a jungle for me. Thanks a lot for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code that starts my node.js server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ": server started on port 8081");
});

// change the port number to whatever port number you want to use
```

You should be looking for that piece of code.

Comment: It depends on what ports are occupied by some process. For example if port 8081 was used he couldn't implement your piece of code.

Comment: @miksiii - the port number was not the point of this answer - it is the sequence of statements.  Obviously, anyone should substitute whatever port number they are expecting to use.  This is an initialization sequence for a node server that works.

Comment: Just saying ;-) Anyway, for me this piece of code wouldn't work because my XAMPP server is running on port 8081 which is alternative to port 80. Any suggestion how to make this work for my case?

Comment: @miksiii - why can't you just change the port number to the port you want to use for this nodejs web server?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your reply. If you could help me solving this it would be really awesome. I tried to change ports also but no luck tho. I can't even make the simplest example work. I instantiate express and trying to do some action when someone visit specific URL -> app.get('/', function(req, res)) { ... } but my function is not being called at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: @miksiii - please start your own new question and include the relevant portion of your server code.  Nobody can help without seeing your actual server code and then asking questions from there and comments on someone else's question are not the place to ask your own question.

Comment: Already did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28015906/nodejs-express-library-port-already-in-use