# Node.js/passport-Facebook authentication

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I am trying to implement a simple Facebook login integration using passport (passport-facebook) authentication middleware. Regarding to [this documentation over here](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/) I have some code here from my **server.js**:

```
var express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy,
    app = express();

// Facebook authentication:
passport.use(
    new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: "fb client id here",
        clientSecret: "fb client secret key here",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost/web-apps/facebook-passport/auth/facebook/"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log("auth is done!");
        done(null, profile);
    })
);

app.get('/web-apps/facebook-passport/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get(
    '/web-apps/facebook-passport/auth/facebook/',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login'
    })
);

app.get('/web-apps/facebook-passport/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('<a href="/web-apps/facebook-passport/auth/facebook">Login with Facebook</a>');
});

app.listen(80);
```

The code basically provides a link that should lead to Facebook authentication (/facebook/auth), ask the client for permission and then redirect user back to my page with some access tokens and client's details. However, when I run my server and try to do that by pressing the link I got

> passport.initialize() middleware not in use

**Passport stacktrace:**

```
Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:44:34)
    at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:228:13)
    at verified (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:179:18)
    at Strategy.app.get.passport.authenticate.successRedirect [as _verify] (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\server.js:22:3)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:195:22
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\strategy.js:183:5
    at passBackControl (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:126:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:143:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

I guess I would need to add something like `app.configuration` to my server-side script but these are gone in express 4.x version. I am wondering how I could fix this?

My node packages are:

> -passport@0.2.1
>
> -passport-facebook@1.03
>
> -express@4.11.1

**** U P D A T E ****

I've added the following code to the top of my script which was result loosing the previous error message:

```
app.use(bodyParser());

// Use the passport package in our application
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Create our Express router
var router = express.Router();
```

However, I got this new error saying

> This authorization code has been used.

This is the stack trace:

```
FacebookTokenError: This authorization code has been used.
    at Strategy.parseErrorResponse (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\lib\strategy.js:198:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:345:16)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:171:43
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:177:18
    at passBackControl (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:124:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\web-apps\facebook-passport\node_modules\passport-facebook\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:143:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:944:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
```

**Solved:**

Problems with URIs.

Comment: So clearly, you can't use a port that is already being used on your server.  So, when you select a different port that doesn't give the "EADDRINUSE" error, do you then put that new port into the URL that you try?  Also, I don't know why you're mentioning `socket.io` since I don't see any `socket.io` code anywhere.  You need to get the plain web server working first anyway.  Also, why is there another web server involved?  If you're using nodejs, it should be your ONE web server on this box unless you're purposely operating multiple web servers at the same host, but on different ports.

Comment: I have read your post.  I don't understand several parts of it, thus I asked a bunch of questions (none of which you cared to answer).  Only one server process can listen on a given port.  If you already have a web server on port 8081, you cannot make another server on the same host that listens on the same port.  Period.  That's how TCP works.  Incoming traffic on a specific port goes to one and only one process that is listening to that port.  Is there more to your question beyond that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this way in your

```
app.get('/web-apps/facebook-passport/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook-signup', { session: false }));
```

instead of

```
app.get('/web-apps/facebook-passport/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
```

I think the problem is that facebook logged you an returned a token, if you dont close the session, facebook is waiting for the same token. Using {session: false} cause facebook close session after the authentication is done. You will be receiving a new token each time you authenticate.

I have had some problems like this before, i m not an expert, but also i solved it in this way.