# Trying to understand where you set the environment for the NODE_ENV command

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a node.js project where I need to be able to switch from a dev environment to a prod environment.

I see a commande to do the switch, which is NODE_ENV=dev npm start.

But how do you configure this for your project?

In other words, I don't see where you set the dev to localhost and prod to 'www...'.

UPDATE:

I thought it would help to show my actual app.js file...

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
var multer = require('multer');
var passport  = require('passport');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var config = require('konfig')();

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());    

app.use('/api', require('./routes/api'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app/custom')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));
app.use('/fileuploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/fileuploads')));
app.use('/img', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/img')));
app.use('/vcards', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/vcards')));
app.use('/pdf', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/app/pdf')));



// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
     res.json({error: err.message});
});

app.all('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/index.html'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't make node js working on port 3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469492/cant-make-node-js-working-on-port-3000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using konfig, you have a dictionary of values loaded in the variable

`config.[filename].[config_key]` --  (from https://github.com/vngrs/konfig/)

so eg `config.[filename].host`.

Seems like you're also looking for [`app.listen()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen) to configure where your app receives requests. How to use app.listen is all over stackoverflow, you can find some pretty good answers about that elsewhere.

---

When you run a script in node, there's a global variable called process that has all kinds of nifty stuff in it. For too much info: [here's a link to the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html).

In the js files that you execute via your command `NODE_ENV=dev npm start`, you can write the following incantation and see your variables show up in the console:

```js
const environment_variable = process.env.NODE_ENV;
console.log("environment_variable is set to:", environment_variable);
```

You can use the values you pass in via environment variables as switches to control the flow or the configuration of the process you're running.

Answer (score 0):

In your js files you would check process.env.NODE_ENV.

For example

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "dev") {
   //use localhost
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NODE_ENV is an environment variable. As such you set NODE_ENV explicitly when you start the application.

You then access the environment variable in code:

```
var environment = process.env.NODE_ENV
```

Or if you are using express:

```
app.get('env')
```